# Angular: How to force recompile directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in arr">
   <custom-directive status-stored-in="obj"></custom-directive>
</div>
```

Problem:

I have page-turn built in for the large amount of `obj`s. Which means that the value of `arr`, representing the current page of `obj`s, will change. However, the `obj` in the `status-stored-in="obj"` part is not refreshed with the change.

Right now my solution is to add a `ng-if` in `customDirective`, flickering its value back and forth to have it force recompiled. Is there any other equivalent, neater way to deal with this?

### Edit:

The start of the custom directive:

```
module.directive 'checkbox', (checkboxHooks) ->
  restrict: 'E'
  scope:
    hook: '='
    hookedTo: '='
    statusStoredIn: '='
  templateUrl: 'templates/checkbox.html'
  link: (scope, element, attr) ->
```

The gist is that it needs to get hold of an object, for storing the `checked` status. The whole of it can be found here: [[coffee](https://github.com/Luxiyalu/angular-checkbox-set/blob/master/angular-checkbox-set.coffee)/[js](https://github.com/Luxiyalu/angular-checkbox-set/blob/master/angular-checkbox-set.js)].

Comment: can you post the directive to show what it's doing? what you are describing doesn't make sense with the limited context you provided here.

Comment: How are you updating the `arr` is it in the angular digest loop?  `$scope.$apply` may also give you some inspiration

Comment: It should be changing, without the need for ng-if. Perhaps it would be helpful to show custom-directive.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your directives link function you need to watch `status-stored-in` for changes and then recompile it e.g.:

```
   link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.$watch('statusStoredIn', function() {
      element.html(statusStoredIn);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
   }
```

Comment: Isn't `$compile(element.contents())` for compiling childNodes? But I need itself to be recompiled.

Comment: I just used `$compile(element.contents())(scope)` to recompile a directive and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: This causes a memory leak. You need to do var watch = scope.$watch... and then after call to $compile do watch(); , otherwise you would have one more watch after every recompile.