# How to refresh custom directive on click button from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have following simple directive define

```
 <div>
  <location-file-upload></location-file-upload>
  <button ng-click="refresh()">Reload</button>
</div>
```

In Controller how can we refresh above directive???

```
$scope.refresh = function(){
//code here
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do by refreshing your directive?

Comment: I just want to remove all selected file from that directive....and open fresh copy of that directive.

Comment: You would have to recompile the directive which would be done from inside the directive.  But there is rarely a need for that, and you can just set the object holding your files to `null`.  Either way, the `button` should be inside the directive template so it can access its properties.  You haven't shown the directive definition so we can't give any other info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: How to force recompile directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579849/angular-how-to-force-recompile-directive)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-if="reRender">
    <location-file-upload></location-file-upload>
    <button ng-click="refresh()">Reload</button>
</div>

$scope.refresh = function(){
    $scope.reRender = false;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.reRender = true;
    )};
}
```